# Post data from Unity (C#) to server (PHP). Each part work itself, but not working together

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I use Unity (C#) to connect to my server code (written in PHP) and send user input to PHP's `$_POST` part.

I tested that server side works well, it can send value to my database (to `user` table). Unity part also works well by itself, but once I try to connect them together, it only sends the empty value to my user table.

Also, the auto-increased ID of the `user` table let me know that C# has properly connected to the php server side.

**Why this is not working, how can I resolve it?**

---

**Edit:** I tried to break line test, and both of c# and php works ok by itself. Once I use C# to send data to php, the data `values (username password email)` are empty.

---

**Data table:**

[image: data table]

**Problem:(No data send to PHP by C#):**

[image: problem:(No data send to PHP by C#)]

---

C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DataInserter : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string inputUserName;
    public string inputPassword;
    public string inputEmail;

    string CreateUserURL = "http://localhost/prevision/insertUser.php";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            CreateUser(inputUserName, inputPassword, inputEmail);
    }

    public void CreateUser(string username, string password, string email)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("UserNamePost", username);
        form.AddField("PasswordPost", password);
        form.AddField("EmailPost", email);

        WWW www = new WWW(CreateUserURL, form);
    }
}
```

---

PHP:

```
<?php
    include("dbConnection.php");

    //check connection
    if(!$connection)
    {
        die("no connection". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    echo "<h1>Connected</h1>"."<br>";

    $UserName = $_POST["UserNamePost"];
    $Password = $_POST["PasswordPost"];
    $Email = $_POST["EmailPost"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO User (UserName,Password,Email) 
            VALUES ('".$UserName."','".$Password."','".$Email."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if(!result)
    {
        echo"Wrong";
    }
    else
    echo "Good";


?>
```

Comment: Tried anything? Care to share the code? We cannot aid what we cannot see

Comment: Okay, so you "*added code*", but ultimately, we can't work with images, please paste a minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint and checking if your variables actually contain data? None of the C# code you've posted shows where you've initialized your variables. Also, as others have stated we need the code pasted as text.

Comment: I tried to break line test, and both of c# and php works ok by itself. Once I use C# to send data to php, the data value(username password email) is empty.

Comment: Just FYI, seems the code follows this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7Ct0sHudKA

Comment: @wingmanFrankie Isn't there the same problem as the guy in the video? By using wrong file at wrong place? The code should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in Unity with sending a Post request.

It all worked fine, but somewhere or somehow Unity/PHP stopped working correctly because of incorrect header types. I switched classes for connecting to the network and setting chunckedtransfer to false. Here is what works for me

```
public IEnumerator CreateUser(string username, string password, string email)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("UserNamePost", username);
    form.AddField("PasswordPost", password);
    form.AddField("EmailPost", email);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(CreateUserURL, form);
    www.chunkedTransfer = false;
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.error == null){
        // you can place code here for handle a succesful post

    } else {
        // what to do on error
    }

}
```

You can then call your function like a Coroutine

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            StartCoroutine(CreateUser(inputUserName, inputPassword, inputEmail));
    }
```